# TryUpdateModelAsync through exception when a value is null

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In the Add page I want to add all details of a staff member but, not all fields have to be added (The user might not want to enter his telephone).

```
if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<StaffMember>(
                    StaffMember, "StaffMember", 
                    s => s.FirstName, s => s.LastName,
                    s => s.Description, s => s.Telephone, s => s.RoomNumber,
                    s => s.SupervisionQuota, s => s.SecondMarkingQuota))
                {
                    StaffMember.UserId = StaffMemberUser.UserId;
                    _Context.StaffMember.Add(StaffMember);
                    await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
```

This is where I get the exception, When I don't enter a value for any of the fields I get

```
SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

Any idea of why is this happening

Comment: This exception means that you are trying to insert a string that is to large to fit in your column. Check the length of the values you are inserting and compare them to size constraints you have set to your varchar/nvarchar columns in the table.

Comment: Thank you! I did see the exception meaning on other stack question, but looked only at string
 fields.
Turns out I was trying to insert 11 characters in the telephone field which is 10 char long!!